# how run a php into another php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates

I have a shortcode that restricts content in wordpress. which first hides content and shows the message and after buying product it shows the sample restricted text.

```
[edd_restrict id="any"]sample restricted text [/edd_restrict]
```

This just work for sample TEXT.
I converted it to PHP like this :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/post-ads.php");?>[/edd_restrict]' );?>
```

But in this way it shows a message to buy a product but after buying product it can not run the PHP inside I mean `<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/post-ads.php");?>` and shows nothing.
is there any way to run this PHP into `<?php echo do_shortcode ?`

Comment: Am I correct if I think that you're trying to include a template on the page once a user has bought a certain product?

Comment: yes. i want to show him post-ads.php when he bought a product. but edd just restricst texts with shortcode not a php file